# How to integrate Windows OnScreen Keyboard (on Asus tablet) api?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am building a game with Unity Engine, and i have some text fields where the user have to enter values, how can i invoke the OnScreen keyboard in this ? I believe i have to use the SurfaceKeyboard class, but i am not able to find the required dll for it. Can anyone suggest me what to do ?

Answer (score -1):

You can show a native keyboard using the `TouchScreenKeyboard` class: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/TouchScreenKeyboard.html

Quite probably you'll need to have either Unity3D iOS or Android add-ons bought and registered to have access to that class.